# Is there any statist policies that have been proven to benefit the economy?

Tags: economy

Refraining from opinions as much as possible, is there any examples where the government intervening in the market that has been proven to have bettered the economy better than the free market could have? I have not yet seen an example of an organization that could not have been bettered by being privatized but that could be due to the bias of being an AnCap.

Comment: In Russia after 1991 most of the industry has been privatized and production dropped by 60%. Russia still struggles to reach its 1990 level.

Comment: @Anixx, Russia is not the case. It suffers not from free economy, but from blatant corruption. For example, a road Adler — Krasnaya Polyana (48 km) costs a whopping $7.5 billion. For comparison, a NASA mission to Mars (55.8 million km) costs only $2.5 billion.

Comment: @bytebuster and the most corrupt and criminal businesses in Russia are those privately owned.

Comment: @Anixx, correct, and these private owners appear to be [magically linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozero) to the topmost government leaders. «Coincidence? I don't think so!» ©

Comment: @bytebuster most are not linked to any government leaders even if some are.

Comment: The whole question is loaded, lazy and unanswerable but even the word “statist” itself is nothing but opinions, are you honestly unable to do better than this when you try to refrain from opinions? Do you work for the government?

Comment: Japan would perhaps be an interesting case. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government-business_relations_in_Japan

Comment: @SVilcans - Japan is hard to pigeonhole. Zaibatsu used to basically control the government to a large extent, IIRC. And a vast majority of large scale economic effects seem to stem from externalities (e.g. demographics, for the last years)

Comment: what does "bettered the economy" even mean? gdp? public welfare? price volatility? employment? if you are looking for companies that have produced much worse output after being privatized, look no further than [british rail](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0155998214000416).

Comment: Voting to close as opinon-based. If you can come up with a narrower question which could be answered objectively then please try again.

Comment: @henning Not really a good example. Privatisation made some things work better, others worse. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:RTGBchart201823.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue with this kind of question is that:

- It is difficult to take into account all of the variables. A public health system may cost X money, but it is hard to assess the benefits it provided by the epidemics that didn't spread, or the taxes and productivity lost to people dying in their youth.
- Conversely, some illuminated can always claim that yes, some policy benefits outweighted its costs, but "if you had not taxed that X money, the private sector would have done the same (and better)". Since we cannot go to a parallel universe in which they followed that course of events and compare, and economics is still much more about faith than science (see the famous [Laffer curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laffer_curve)), even the wildest claim can be accepted if they match the public preconceptions.

The most famous example in the capitalist country about state intervention would be the New Deal, yet (as mentioned above) is not without critics. In another line of thought, the industrialization of the SU and China can be pointed as other examples, although the massive human suffering during those periods make those points even more opinable<sup>1</sup>). Yet, if you need some examples, we can talk about:

- [some roads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstate_Highway_System) that almost nobody uses
- [nobody uses trains nowadays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Transcontinental_Railroad#Political_authorization_and_funding)
- [that small dam, and all the electricity produced there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoover_Dam)
- [a small canal for ships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panama_Canal)
- [area development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennessee_Valley_Authority)
- [response to environmental crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_Bowl#U.S._government_response)
- [a data network you might have heard about](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Internet)

as a few examples, in just a country that is famously against government intervention.

Note that those also don't take into account instances of Government sponsored scientific research being passed to private companies (like nuclear power generation, or penicilin).

<sup>1</sup>: And you could also get into a discussion over which part of those human sufferings were inevitable due to the industrialization plans alone, and which part of those were caused by other factors.

Comment: **TL;DR**: it's really really hard to do a randomized double blind trial on the whole economy :)

Comment: Re: listing specific government-funded projects: (1) you're ignoring the vast bulk of projects that were NOT beneficial to the economy (on the margins). For every Hoover Dam, there's a dead Aral Sea. (2) Your examples run afoul of your own second bullet point. Building a Hoover Dam wasn't a statist policy in a sense that it couldn't be built by private enterprise if they had unfettered access (e.g. didn't have to negotiate for access to resources that government controls). Of course, we have no parallel universe to test that hypotheses.

Comment: **TL;DR#2**: Attribution is very hard. Usually impossible.

Comment: @user4012 Are you sure you want to give private enterprises an unfettered access to build a 20k square kilometers lake? Or even funnier make it negotiate with ALL land owners whose property would be flooded?

Answer (score 5):

Consequences of privatization in Russia and the former USSR.

- Saratov Aviation Plant (liquidated in 2011, all the buildings went under decay and maraudering).
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
- Chkalov Tashkent Aviation plant. Went bankrupt. Then turned into museum, then into a mechanical factory for consumer goods. No aviation production resuming is planned
  [image]
  [image]
- Aviakor aviation plant. Formerly produced more than a thousand of Tu-154 airliners, up to 76 a year. Now builts An-140 small regional airliner, totally built 11 since 2005. Pure losses 761 million rubles in 2013.
  [image]
- Aviastar, an aviation plant of the Tupolev holding. Now produces about one(1) Tu-204 a year. Total losses are 2,583 billion rubles (2011).
- Riga Autobus Factory. Went bankrupt, liquidated.
  [image]
- Lvov Autobus Plant. Went bankrupt in 2015
  [image]

Et cetera. After the privatization, the industrial production in Russia dropped by 60% and stil havent restored to the level of 1990.

The only reliably working companies in Russia are still those which are state-owned, such as banks Sberbank and VTB24(former Soviet Vneshtorgbank), Gazprom, Aeroflot etc.

Comment: The alternative interpretation is that the Soviet government was wasting tons of resources on these manufacturing plants when cheaper/more reliable/higher quality(pick one or all) planes could be built elsewhere and traded for with resources that Russia actually had comparative advantage in producing.

Comment: @lazarusL there are fields where Russian state-owned and private businesses are operating at the same time, such as banks or airlines. So far only the state-owned companies work more or less reliably. The only two reliable banks in Russia are the Sberbank and VTB24, putting money in all other banks is a lottery with hundreds of bankruptsies. The same is with airlines, recently a large fully private airline Transaero went bankrupt, before that Red Wings and Siberia.

Comment: @lazarusL The same is with real estate (residential) construction. Hundreds of construction companies went bankrupt leaving the hunreds of thousands of people who opted to buy apartments before completion fooled withot all the money they collected tens of years. It is only the government that helps the people and compensates them losses. And yet the construction still havent reached the volume of the 1980s...

Comment: @lazarusL "cheaper/more reliable/higher quality(pick one or all) planes could be built elsewhere and traded for with resources" - may be, but so far the civil air transportation in Russia have not reached the level of 1990. On the other hand you can always argue that under market economy people can restrain from air travel because those routes inefficient or that the people themselves inefficient and should not live because they are not demanded by the market (as the ideologues of market economy in Russia, e.g. Chubais proclaimed).

Comment: I mean, I can't argue with you. It's hard to run a business that has to compete with state owned, subsidised companies in a country with severe corruption problems. Generally, people try to contrast state ownership with a free enterprise system rather than one dominated by cronyism.

Comment: @lazarusL Sberbank, VTB25, Aeroflot, Gasprom (at least in 2014 and 2013) are not subsidized, they are profitable. Contrary to this it is private companies that usually get in trouble and (successfully or not) seek government's subsidies and bailouts.

Comment: [Aeroflot](http://www.interfax.com/newsinf.asp?id=322285) [Sberbank](http://www.themoscowtimes.com/business/article/russian-banks-ask-state-for-more-mortgage-subsidies/523609.html)

Comment: @lazarusL these are common subsidies for certain routes, not only Aeroflot is subject for them. If not these subsidies, the companies would not fly to the far parts of Russia and people would be left without transportation. The airlines would still remain profitable...

Comment: @lazarusL  Regarding Sberbank, etc... It is the state's subsidy for banks to give more mortgage loans, which are needed for people who wants to buy apartments. All banks are eligible, it is just that Sberbank and VTB 24 only agreed to take part in this non-beneficial project as their social mission. Other banks just refuse to participate in the program.

Answer (score 1):

Some widely cited examples:

- Patents for describing new things to make and/or new ways to make things, so that any competent craftsmen can make them, in exchange for a monopoly for a limited time (such as 14 - 20 years).  (Such patents privatize the collection of economic rents on the innovations.)
- Government subsidies for building railroads through wildernesses.  (In the United States, these subsidies were typically to private companies, and much of the subsidy was in the form of alternating strips of land near the railroad, which the railroad could sell as part of developing the region.)
- Government enforcement of trademarks.  For example, laws against counterfeiting currency.

Comment: Government subsidies for railroads aren't example of beneficial statist policy. It's an example of one statist policy (subsidy) cancelling effect of another statist policy (government grabbing ownership of land in the first place).

Comment: Patents and copyrights that you have to defend yourself- I wouldn't call that statist. Patents are possibly the fraudulent law ever.

Answer (score 1):

the economist, pointed out that the S.Korean government invested in the steel industry when they were a poor agricultural country to fantastic effect to their later economy.

He also points out that, I think it was one of the Tudors that encouraged the growth of the textile industry in England. That’s maybe not quite what you were thinking about in terms of government, but the point is, it wasn’t private investment.

It’s also very well known that most of the essential research to do with the Internet was government funded and just as importantly and probably more importantly, the actual technology base: schooling, colleges and universities.

It’s also worth examining the contrapositive, what happens when a free-market is introduced. It’s probably not so well known, that after the introduction of the free market in the former Soviet Union, that their mortality rate *rose* substantially. It’s perhaps not surprising they called it ‘economic shock treatment’. Luckily the patient didn’t die, but then again, do countries die? It’s people that do. Just as importantly, it was seen as a kleptocracy, a kind of robbers capitalism. Probably just like the ol’ Wild West when capitalism ran free and wild. But people forget and then they don’t like it when they see it reflected back to them.

Another example here would be Chile under the Pinochet regime where a free market was imposed by a military coup (and which was backed by all accounts by the USA)  which toppled a democratically elected Socialist government, that of Salvador Allende. That’s not forgetting the ‘cost’ of a reign of terror and the thousands of ‘the disappeared’. (I suppose it’s not a cost if you don’t have to face it). The Chicago trained free-market economists (the ‘Chicago boys’) were given a free hand and more or less trashed the economy. The economy was rescued by bringing it back into government hands, something that we saw in the West a decade ago; and even after a decade after this debacle, the economy hadn’t reached pre-Pinochet levels.

By all accounts, China didn’t make that mistake when they introduced a competitive market. They introduced it on their own terms. Perhaps they learnt from the Soviet and Chilean experience what it’s like to be sold an economic ideology as a universal panacea by a bunch of shady snake-oil merchants.

Comment: I don’t know quite what’s happening here, his economists name is *Ha-Joon Chang* and I’ve edited it a few times to put that in and the edits refusing to take.

Comment: *"their mortality rate sank substantially"* -> I assume you mean the exact opposite ?

Comment: @Evargalo: Yes, your assumption is correct. I’m not sure what I was thinking of atcthe time. I’ll fix it. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: This site simply does not like Ha Joon Chang!

Answer (score 0):

I am a moderate libertarian. However, I think some statist policy is good. And not all can be easily replaced by market equivalent. Not yet at least.

Also CMIIW. What counts as statist may vary. For example, does having public polices instead private police statism?

Some of the idea may be wrong. However, the idea here "have a case". For example, it is possible that government solution is better than the market solution. It may not be, but there is a reasonable case that it may.

Some goods have very high transaction costs. A resources allocation in case of elot of externalities can be corrected well by governments.

Well, government itself is statist. To have one centralized power that guard security is pretty cost effective compared to competing "private polices" that probably wage war against each other.

If we have private police, what would stop some dictators to just pay those polices to silent opponents? So a democratic system where people can't easily become dictators is a plus.

Confucius once found a woman that avoid paying taxes by not living in a city. The woman's husband was eaten by tiger. http://www.sacred-texts.com/cfu/eoc/eoc10.htm .

Here, we can say that a king that found a city provide a service. No body forces that woman to live in **his city**. In fact, the woman that don't want to pay tax avoid paying taxes and are not punished in anyway. They just get eaten by lions. Hence, founding a city and maintaining it, which is a government and hence statist function, improves economy.

US government is a relatively capitalistic countries. Without US government you will have to deal with Osama bin Laden and Kim Jong Un yourself. Most of us do not have the political skills and power to deal with them. So forming a government that's reasonably capitalistic add value to economy.

When government build infrastructure, the total economic result can often be more than the cost of the roads. The roads improve land value. Places connected by the road see the land value improves. In a sense, building roads cause "positive" externalities to land owners.

Again it's hard to privatize road building. If you just charge toll, you underbuild road. If you ask money from every land owners whose land value improves, then a single land owner that doesn't want to will make the whole thing fail. So a government that decide to tax land and build road can improve economy.

Existence of police also add values to economy. Most of us are alive simply because murder is illegal. Here, collapse of government results in chaos and looting. So the government have some benefits there.

Governments can also standardize things.

Imagine if there is no rule against putting harmful substances in supermarket? Well, that doesn't mean we all gonna get poisons. What will happen is people will only buy from trusted vendors. But then we have very few big businesses that can be trusted.

Having governments giving standard that food labeling must be honest, does not contain poison, etc allow more biz to thrive. Now I can go to local small market knowing that that my food will be save. I know that because the owner of that small market will go to jail if it isn't.

Some libertarians may say that forced labeling on food is not a statist policy but part of normal government's function in preventing fraud. However, what's exactly the standard is need to be decided by "somebody". So having a government does that may improves economy.

Governments also institute marriage. Before paternity tests, there is no easy way to know who the child of a man is. Hence, without knowing that, men cannot know how to inherit his wealth accurately. By institution of marriage, men that knows that he can inherit his wealth to his children will work harder. That improves economy.

Of course, now, marriage is totally useless in this regard because we can always check paternity. This is one of a sample where statist action, namely defining marriage, may have been good economically in some situation, but bad in another situation.

Governments often and can force people to get vaccinated. That is actually a good thing. People don't die and that means economy improves. Gee. I wonder why not getting vaccinated is legal but porn sometimes isn't. But that's beyond this question.

Let's examine something more controversial. Can statist racial discrimination be good for economy? Well, Israel discriminate against muslims in their airport and that leads to safer airports. So that's statist, not libertarian, but add value to economy.

The same way, muslim countries discriminate against jews and non muslims. That too add value to the economy because it protects their people's feeling from ideas obnoxious to them.

In fact, separating people that don't get along with each other through discrimination actually add value for both people. I am pretty confused with the way liberal democracy works. Why don't they discriminate based on race and religions to the point of absolute?

If some people like to kill those who blaspheme Muhammad and some people like to draw Muhammad cartoon, those people shouldn't live together and statist discrimination would improve life of both.

There are many problems that government, and only government can solve. The fact that governments' solution make the problem even worse is a different story.

However, most governments are getting better and better for capitalists. That's because capitalists can simply move to another country if their governments sucks.

Currently we have plenty of poverty. If governments would give money to people with no children and tax children, poverty can be gone. Governments can also sterilize poor parents in exchange of welfare.

Of course, what governments nowadays do is the exact opposite. Government encourage the poor to breed by welfare.

But hei, if we don't like it, we can just go to another country. The fact that we don't shows that the plus is still more than the minus.

Most libertarians and anarcho capitalists would think that governments are bad and need to be abolished. Me, I see some good in governments. I think governments should just be "privatized" rather than abolished.

When governments compete with one another like private companies they tend to be nicer. In fact, that's what happen now and that's why our species are very prosperous now.